# Reusing code for sharing/saving pdf document

Tags: android, pdf

So I have a fragment where I show the user terms and conditions for something and those terms and conditions are in the form of pdf file which is retrieved from the server.

This is the code that retrieves the pdf and gives the pdfView an inputstream to show the data.

```
class RetrievePDFFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
    }
}
```

So far so good.
But now I have to add the functionality to share and save the document.
The problem is that I have to use other pieces of code to accomplish the task.
And since I cant share the document without downloading it, its a little messy.
Heres how I download the document.

```
private void downloadPDFContent(){
    String fileName = getCurrentDocumentName();;
    String urlToDownload = !secondDocument ? documentUrl1 : documentUrl2;

    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName);

    if (outputFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlToDownload));
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

The problem comes when trying to share the document, Its just wrong to put 200ms delay before trying to share it, because no one knows how slow a connection can be sometimes and it wont work.

```
private void shareDocument() {
    downloadPDFContent();

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), getCurrentDocumentName());

            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", outputFile);

            Intent share = new Intent();
            share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("application/pdf");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share document"));
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

Does anyone have any better ideas how can I achieve those 3 tasks - using inputstream to load the doc for the user to view and to share/save it also while reusing code and not doing it in different and unstable ways?

**UPDATE: I added a broadcastreceiver to start when the downloading is finished, instead of waiting a fixed amount of time like i do here.
Which is one idea better but still not what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have been using many legacy tools for this task and it is not clear do you have business constraints for it or not.

If your business use case just to download pdf and share it with another android app within your device, I would use `Kotlin Flow` for the async download task.

When you download your pdf and save it in storage, you could use a callback from `Kotlin Flow` as a trigger for your sharing intent. You would not need anymore any delay.

Please note, depends on your business use case you could use `ContentProvider` to give access to your app's files and `p2p` 3rd party tools for downloading and sharing your files.

Comment: we are using java on this project and i wont be able to use that

Comment: ```RxJava``` is another alternative. It is right way to use tools natural to the platform, but ```AsyncTask``` has been deprecated already https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask and usage of ```Handler``` is limited now for very few scenarios.

Comment: If you can not bring 3rd party library at all, take a look on Android ```Service```, Java ```ThreadPoolExecutors```, Android ```ResultReceiver``` and Android ```Intent``` ability to pass ```Parcelable``` objects within. Altogether it will help you to separate your network layer from the rest of your code and to notify your code in ```Main``` thread from another thread.